# Solr/Lucene contextual SynonymFilter

Tags: solr, lucene, solrcloud

I created a version of the SynonymFilterFactory to load the Synonym configuration file from the DB, refreshing every X seconds because of the customer requirements.

Now I need something similar, I need to use different synonyms for different value of a parameter in the query, I will use the fq parameter to do this because every user only search on documents that will match a categorization term on a field.

So I need to create the SynonymFilter, with different configuration based on the fq parameter, e.g.: if fq=A I use a set o synonyms, if B another SET.

How can I read the fq parameter in the create method of a FilterFactory? Where can I search for this query parameter?

Answer (score 0):

I'll be satisfied also to catch the request original get values in the filter factory